# Google Cloud SDK Datastore Emulator JRE Version Mismatch?

Tags: java, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-sdk

I've been struggling with this all day. I am try to follow the directions [here](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/datastore-emulator) to get a local datastore emulator running. When I get to the step of invoking `gcloud beta emulators datastore start`, I repeatedly get the error

`ERROR: (gcloud.beta.emulators.datastore.start) The java executable on your PATH is not a Java 7+ JRE. The Google Cloud Datastore emulator requires a Java 7+ JRE installed and on your system PATH`

I have both JDK 9X and JRE 9X installed, and my PATH looks like the following

```
# export JAVA_9_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/"
export JRE_9_HOME="/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home"
export JAVA_9_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home"

export JAVA_HOME=$JRE_9_HOME
# export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_9_HOME


# Setting JRE into Path
# PATH="$PATH:$JRE_HOME"
# export PATH

# Setting JDK into Path
PATH="$PATH:$JAVA_HOME"
export PATH

# export JAVA_OTHER="/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Home"
# # Setting JDK into Path
# PATH="$PATH:$JAVA_OTHER"
# export PATH
```

As you can see I have been trying many combinations with no luck :(

Comment: It may be that the Google Cloud Datastore emulator doesn't recognize JDK 9, perhaps because the version string is "9.0.1" rather than "1.7.xxxx" or perhaps because the run-time image has a new layout (no top-level "jre" directory, not rt.jar or tools.jar).  You may need to check out the forums and bug reports to see if it has been fixed.

Comment: downgrading to 1.8.X ended up being the only recourse, unfortunately. Once I did that it worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up having to delete JDK 9 and install 8, which has (it looks like) a compatible version string (1.8.X), on the suggestion of @alan-bateman

Comment: Did you submit a bug so that the maintainers of Google Cloud Datastore emulator know then have an issue on newer JDK releases?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure Java 9 is really operationnal on your setup ?
What is the output of the command `java -version` ?

if you are running on mac you should have this (in your bash_profile or bashrc)

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

On another linux box you can add the following to your bashrc/bash_profile :

```
export JAVA_HOME=/home/myuser/dev/tools/java/jdk9
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

where  /home/myuser/dev/tools/java/jdk9 is the directory where you unpacked your JDK

from now if you open a **new** terminal (or if you source your file `. ~/.bashrc`) and type the command

```
java -version
```

You should see something like :

```
java version "9.0.1"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.1+11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.1+11, mixed mode)
```

Please notice that when you export PATH variable, JAVA_HOME/bin needs to be set before the $PATH in order to take precedence,

Comment: `java -version` returns 

    `java version "9.0.1"
    Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.1+11)
    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.1+11, mixed mode)`

 `./java_home -v 1.8` returns 
`Unable to find any JVMs matching version "1.8".
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home` but can't I just set the version to 9.0.1?